# How can I restore an answer deleted by a ♦ moderator?

Tags: support, specific-answer, moderators, vote-to-undelete

I answered

[Ignore NaN when adding input values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48447603/295783)

And then realised there was a duplicate when the question was marked as such.

I liked my answer and copied it to the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/48447658/295783

It got deleted by a ♦ mod with the comment

> Please don't post duplicate answers. If the questions are the same, answer one and vote to close the other(s) as duplicate. If they're not the same then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question.

Fair enough - so I deleted it on the original question to comply with the above comment, but cannot undelete it from the dupe since it was deleted by a ♦ moderator.

How can I restore it now that it is complying with his wishes?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's quite simple; just flag the answer (the one you want to undelete) for moderator attention and explain the situation.

Note that you need to provide a substantially more compelling rationale than "I want this undeleted". You need to have already made an edit fixing the problem(s) leading to the post's deletion (or otherwise arranged for those problems to be resolved) *before* you raise the moderator flag, and you need to explain *in the text of the flag itself* what you have done and why it is ready for a moderator's re-review.