# Is any mention of ChatGPT still against the rules?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, a few days later I solved the problem myself with the help of ChatGPT and I figured I would post the solution to my question in case anyone stumbles across my question looking for a similar problem/solution.

In my answer I just mentioned that I had used ChatGPT to *help* solve my problem. I did not copy **any of the content it generated* from the output window of ChatGPT in my solution. I just used ChatGPT to brainstorm ways to solve my problem. I did not just copy and paste from ChatGPT to Stack Overflow (nor did I copy and paste from ChatGPT to my program...). Every single character in my solution was typed by my fingers on my keyboard.

I added comments to the code, I added explaining text around, I separated and organized the functions cleanly in text form so that the person who finds my question and solution has an easy time to read what I wrote and following the instructions.

My entire solution got deleted, not because it was written by ChatGPT, but because *I just mentioned ChatGPT!!*

Is this seriously this platform's policy? Is this enforceable? Is this website trying to kill itself? Why should I spend time trying to fix other people's problems when you guys just delete the things that I wrote with my own fingers.

Comment: Mentioning ChatGPT isn't against the rules, no, and it never was. Posting content from it *is*. You state you didn't here, which likely means that the fact the mentioned you used ChatGPT to help you draw conclusions was noise and probably wasn't needed. You were probably best off not mentioning it at all.

Comment: *If* what you state is true, then the reaction of the users could be incorrect. As we can't see the post (there's no link or screenshot for <10k users), then being able to provide more than a suggestion/conjecture is difficult.

Comment: Just *mentioning* ChatGPT [isn't banned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), but why would you do so to begin with? If you use *none* of its output for your answer, then mentioning it only adds the risk that someone misinterprets it – after all, why would you mention it otherwise?

Comment: [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127680/6296561) (10k), [repost 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76251726/6296561) (10k), [repost 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76852590/6296561) (not currently 10k)

Comment: Do not repost posts that were deleted. If you disagree with the deletion, you can come here and ask why it was deleted. Reposting deleted content is the fastest way to get yourself in trouble.

Comment: Just post your answer, there's no need for all the nonsense junk added to it.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ask here or raise a mod flag*

Comment: Blargh, reposting the post once, let alone *twice*, *is* wrong though. You should have come to meta or raised a moderator flag after the first deletion. Certainly not after it was deleted for a second time and you'd posted it for a **third** time.

Comment: [Why were you so rude?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76852590/1) Everyone here does good for free. It's not fair to repay them with insults. When you are unhappy, come to META, or talk about it in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com)

Comment: From the moment the comment is posted here, even deleted, it remains visible to the moderators.

Comment: We believe you. Now start using the d***** [spell checker](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=answear) (built into every major web browser (nothing to install)).

Comment: You conveniently left out the part where [you did this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76852590/1). Not cool.

Comment: Regardless, whether something is against the rules or not is just the first barrier. The second barrier is: how will it be received? Something on-topic can still be considered unwanted quality-wise and thus wisdom is to not post it. I wouldn't mention ChatGPT. Not ever. Just don't, it is pretty much a trigger word now. The circumstances and the way things are handled have made that pretty much inevitable.

Answer (score 30):

The problem here isn't that you mention ChatGPT; it's that you imply your answer was generated by ChatGPT. Your original answer started with:

> I solved it with Reflection (and chatGPT...), posting solution in case somebody stumbles across this page looking for answears.

To me - and presumably the mod that deleted it - that reads as claiming that the content in the answer is written by ChatGPT (because you state it was solved by ChatGPT). As a result it was deleted as *content generated by ChatGPT* [is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).

If your content isn't generated by ChatGPT, then any mention of ChatGPT is noise and doesn't belong in the post - for the same reason that [greetings, thanks etc. are removed from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950). We aren't interested in whether ChatGPT helped you find a solution, because it's not relevant to the answer. If you used a specific article to help you create an answer, and you felt that it is directly related to the answer, then providing links to that article can be helpful; however, ChatGPT provides no such option to provide the source of where it "learned" about the subject matter.

---

For your [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76251726/2029983), this was deleted because you reposted a mod deleted answer; this *is* against the rules. Reposting a mod-deleted post is not OK. If you need a post that was deleted by a moderator restored then raise a custom moderator flag: [How can I restore an answer deleted by a ♦ moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362699/how-can-i-restore-an-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator)

It was also not helpful to include meta commentary in the repost.

---

You then [reposted it *again*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76852590), which was again the incorrect action, though it is now how it should have looked to start with (thanks to another user's edit). There is no noise, and it doesn't have the look or feel of a ChatGPT answer. If you had provided that answer in the first place I suspect it never would have been deleted.

Comment: But they also say in the meta question some of the code was written by ChatGPT, "I added comments to the code" etc & strangely don't deny copying it, just copying & pasting it.

Comment: I'm putting *some* trust in the user, I will admit that, @philipxy . It sounds like, from the post here, the OP did test the solution and likely adapted the solution from ChatGPT to their own environment. That likely *did* involve copy and pasting the code it provided and then altering it. One of the biggest problems we face with ChatGPT content is that it isn't tested, and users that provide the content have no way of knowing if it's valid without doing said testing.

Comment: I do think this is a fair way to address it, it's not like we go around saying "I solved this problem using Reflection and Google" or "Reflection and Bing". The important bit is that it shouldn't be a direct untested copy-paste into answers just as we shouldn't be directly copy pasting solutions from google into answers.

Comment: that it is noise is your interpretation. Aren't all those opposing AI here also for crediting the source the poster got their information from? So he didn't need to mention chatgpt, doesn't mean he has to be penalized for doing it either. If all these people are so superficially against even the mention of chatgpt, whoever deleted the post could have as well just edited out the mention of "chatgpt" from the post, as he would have done for a thank you or whatever thing he considers noise, keeping the answer intact as long as it's not blatant vandalism

Comment: "that it is noise is your interpretation." - no, it is established policy for the entire Stack Exchange network, going back 14+ years, based in the principles described on the site tour, with the common consensus understanding of essentially everyone who actively looks after the site content. "Aren't all those opposing AI here also for crediting the source the poster got their information from?" when you are **citing** something, yes, so as to avoid plagiarism. Not if it's "I asked ChatGPT / used a search engine / cracked open my college textbook, and thought carefully about what I read".

Comment: "If all these people are so superficially against even the mention of chatgpt, whoever deleted the post could have as well just edited out the mention of "chatgpt" from the post". You misunderstand. It is not that someone disliked the fact that you were talking about ChatGPT. It is that, because you talked about ChatGPT, it resulted in someone else *misunderstanding what you said, and thinking that you were sharing actual ChatGPT content*.

Comment: (To be clear, you should not cite what ChatGPT told you, first off because posting that is what is banned, and second because ChatGPT **cannot actually do logical reasoning** and is essentially only figuring out what word makes sense to write next based on its mathematical model. A lot of the time, it will happen to say something sensible, because its idea of "what word comes next" is informed by people who were usually saying sensible things. But it is best treated as a glorified search engine that sometimes makes up web pages that don't exist.

Comment: "It is that, because you talked about ChatGPT, it resulted in someone else misunderstanding what you said, and thinking that you were sharing actual ChatGPT content." As mentioned many many times already, in cases like these, *judge a post on it's merit* rather than what *you think* was used to create it. If the post really is bad, delete it for being so. If *you* think mention of chatgpt is noise, suggest a helpful edit to remove this. If you have enough reputation on the site your edit will be applied immediately.

Comment: And to be clear, you don't need to explain if chatgpt can do logical reasoning or not. I am also aware enough of what it is or isn't capable of. Many of those who think banning all use of AI here is a dumb idea, don't do so because they think chatgpt or AI is the ultimate solution for any kind of question that can be asked here

Answer (score 0):

Currently ChatGTP and other LLMs are optimised to produce plausible answers.  They try to write text that passes for a human with no concern for accuracy.

This means that they are really dangerous for fields like legal citations, wikipedia and stack overflow, since they happily make up fake references, with the correct format of the url etc etc so that it all looks completely genuine.

However for Code, legal or anything else that actually needs to work it causes havoc, since it looks like an expert has written it complete with valid looking references.

So I can see the rational for the ban, however the flip side is that is produces nice well written answers that you can then use as the starter for actually solving the problem and coming up with a correct tested answer.

The challenge with a ban and especially this case is that it encourages people to lie and not mention any input from ChatGPT.

My thought is that a better policy would be full disclosure, so that users are aware that the answer used AI along with how the AI was used.

e.g. Text written by AI, code corrected by me and confirmed working.
or Text written by AI, code looks plausible but not checked.
or wrote myself and tided up language with AI

My prompt to the AI (ChatGTP ver0.00) was XYZ with the following modifiers ABC

People that use AI with out disclosure should be subject to the same down rating as people that copy and past with out attribution and other similar forms of plagiarism.

Stackoverflow answers have two challenges code and prose, and there is a large part of the coding community that is bad at prose and it is even worse in the other direction.

ChatGPT and other LLMs are good at prose, so this helps the coders that can not write produce nice answers.

People that are reputation hunters and using ChatGPT to quickly generate untested answers are unlikely to stop doing it because it is banned.  I think they are more likely to behave well, if rewarded for good answers and penalised for poor answers, and a major part of a good answer is providing sources.

In case of an LLM it is model, version, inputs and modifiers.